# Can a case be created automatically?

Tags: case

Can a case be created automatically (as you can with a task) without resorting to custom code?

Comment: Could you please explain your requirement in details? You can use Web-to-Case and Email-to-Case/On-Demand Email-to-Case to create cases from website's and customer emails.

Comment: Can an activity, such as setting an opportunity to 'Won', trigger the creation of a case as part of standard functionality or does it require a custom trigger to be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use the Process Builder to do this as of Spring 2015!

*Setup > Create > Workflow & Approvals > Process Builder*

Answer (score 2):

You will need custom code to do what you are looking for. As of now, there is no way to create another record (with the exception of tasks) from a workflow rule.

You can also vote for the idea.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrieAAC

Comment: No longer true, `Process Builder` can do it as @RyanP suggests.

Answer (score 1):

In the current spring 14 release there is workflow to visual workflow functionality in a pilot mode. This means only a select group of customers and salesforce partners are trying this out at this time.

If that functionality is eventually released to production (#safeharbor) I believe it would enable you to also create cases (an other new records) without custom code.